# In a single solution, using forms from one project in another

Tags: c#, winforms, solution

I have a Solution, and in it they are five projects. The Client project draws dependency from PokeEngine.dll, a project within the same solution. The non-form classes within PokeEngine.dll work as intended, but the form classes seem to have some issues.

The target framework is .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

Here are some code snippets, I don't know if they'll be useful.

In the Client namespace:

```
static class Program
{
    // the forms used by the client
    public static frmGameWindow gameWindow;
    public static frmMenus menuWindow;
    public static frmBattleWindow battleWindow; // exists in PokeEngine project
    public static frmPokeDex pokedexWindow; // exists in PokeEngine project

    ....

    // main entry point of the client
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        initClient();

        Application.Run(menuWindow);

        destroyGame();
    }

    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes client settings.
    /// </summary>
    public static void initClient()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

        gameWindow = new frmGameWindow();
        menuWindow = new frmMenus();
        battleWindow = new frmBattleWindow(); // causes the program to not run
        pokedexWindow = new frmPokeDex(); // doesn't cause the program to not run

        // local settings (localhost) - testing purposes only
        //connectionInfo = new ConnInfo("localhost", 4000);

        // live settings (my house)
        connectionInfo = new ConnInfo("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 4000);

        gameWindow.Text = connectionInfo.gameName;

        Client.setUpNetwork(connectionInfo.gameName);
    }
}
```

Thing is, the code works on my computer, and my computer alone. Other computers don't run my program when

```
battleWindow = new frmBattleWindow(); // causes the program to not run
```

isn't commented out, yet frmPokedexWindow is in the same project and runs just fine.

However, when I try to .Show() pokedexWindow, it doesn't show it. When battleWindow was initialized by another method (rather than initClient), the game ran, but .Show() methods called to it wouldn't.

as I stated before, this error only happens on other computers, my computer (both in debug and as an .exe) run the game as intended... Any reason for this?

Comment: Do you get an exception? Did you check the Windows error log?

Comment: Is there any output if you start your .exe from a command line?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions, and I am not in possession of the Win8 machine, my friends are. I could ask one of them to try and check the error log. And I'm not sure if there is any output, nor am I sure how to go about checking it from the command prompt. I'll get some research done and ask for their help. It's really cumbersome to develop for Win8 when you don't have a Win8 machine, heheh...

Comment: @EugenRieck: I've ran my application via command prompt in Win7 and there was no output displayed, even after closing the program (expecting 0 to be printed). I can try checking the potential output in Win8, if there would be any.

Comment: @Silver Ofcourse I ment output generated on the system where the error occurs ...

Comment: A new bit of development: I pinpointed the issue to initialization of the frmBattleWindow form. pokedexWindow and battleWindow are both in the PokeEngine namespace. Now, as you can see, the code that initializes pokedexWindow runs without issue, but when I comment out the code that initializes the battle window, it stops working on other people's computers - not just win8. It only works on my laptop and my desktop... No exceptions are being thrown, however... Any advice?

Comment: I meant to say "when I uncomment out the code that initializes the battle window" Also, when it is commented out, it runs fine. The code that initializes battle windows used to exist in a separate method. When that method was called, the battle window never showed up. Moving it to the Program class and initializing it off the Main process just causes the game to never load (as initClient exists before Application.Run). Just wish I could pinpoint why this is happening.